# How to check what data triggered updated in Vue?

Tags: vuejs2

```
updated: function() {
    console.log("updated");
    this.$emit("render-vue", this.$el.offsetHeight);
  },
```

This works fine enough...but in my app, `props` get updated (which I don't care about), and then there is a `fetch()` that updates `data`, resulting in additional DOM rendering.

So, that means that I get *2* 'updated' events in succession!

Essentially, I *only* want `updated` to perform the `$emit` when `data` has been fully updated and the DOM is finished.

Currently, `$emit` is happening 2 times in succession, and that's not helping situation - IT DOM gets updated with `props` and then right after that another `updated` occurs when `data` gets updated after `fetch()`.

Now, I could `watch` - tried that. The issue there is that `$emit` will fire off before all DOM is `updated`, sending the wrong info as *argument.*

It's almost like I need to `watch` a specific piece of `data`...and then, and only then, have `updated` send the `$emit`.

For additional context, there are no *children* - this is a *child* component.

I can *probably* get this to work by using a `setTimeout()`...but come, on! That's sloppy!

Comment: Can you add some code to explain briefly what you tried ?

Comment: Actually, this is a poor question, and as it turns out the issue I was experiencing was not related to this question. 

Comment: Ah ok, let us know if this is still revelant

Comment: Not really. Up to community to remove or not. I m good with it, and answer below is also good.

Comment: If the anwser below is good, accept it at good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code block that fetches the data, set a property to indicate new data is available

```
fetch(url)
    .then(() => {
        // whatever you're doing with the data
        this.newData = true;
    });
```

Check this state variable in the `updated` hook

```
updated() {
    if (this.newData) {
        this.$emit("render-vue", this.$el.offsetHeight);
        this.newData = false;
    }
}
```